# Validation errors not showing after I ajax a rails form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using ajax-rails to render my form and validations stopped working. When I click to submit empty for which should validate, validation does not take effect and backend log shows it posted empty form. If I don't use ajax it works fine. I don't know what I am missing.

**model**

```
class ClockEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :purpose, presence: true # I validated the attribute
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container" id="new-clock-entry">
  <%= link_to 'New Clock Entry', new_clock_entry_path, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
</div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for clock_entry, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :purpose %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New Clock Entry</h1>

<%= render 'form', clock_entry: @clock_entry %>

<%= link_to 'Back', clock_entries_path %>
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#new-clock-entry a').hide().parent().append("<%= j render 'form', clock_entry: @clock_entry %>")
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#new-clock-entry form').remove();
$('#new-clock-entry a').show();
$('table#clock-entry tbody').append("<%= j render @clock_entry %>");
```

**controller**

```
def new
  @clock_entry = ClockEntry.new
end

def create
    @clock_entry = current_user.clock_entries.new(clock_entry_params)
    @clock_entry.set_time_in

    respond_to do |format|
      if @clock_entry.save
        format.js { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Clock entry was successfully created.' }
        format.html { redirect_to @clock_entry, notice: 'Clock entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @clock_entry }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @clock_entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You don't have a `format.js` line on the else when `@clock_entry.save` fails. Don't you have an error saying it can't find the view?

Comment: @arieljuod Wow true. But when I added that it renders a new ajax form under the ajax form instead of rendering on the form. Now I have double forms.

Comment: I guess you are using "append" on your javascript without removing the old form.

Comment: Can you provide an answer for this? That will shed more light into it. Am not so crafted with Ajax

Comment: I'm not sure what's your current view and your current ajax response. You have to target the element you don't want, call "remove()" and then append the new form.

Comment: can you check my `create.js.erb` and `new.js.erb` the tags am using are there.

Comment: I don't know what's in your view, I have no idea the selectors you have to use. You seem to be calling `remove()` on a form, maybe the selector is wrong. Maybe you can try `$('table#clock-entry tbody').html("<%= j render @clock_entry %>");` instead of append to replace the whole content. But again, you are now showing the html view, I have no idea what the css selectors would be.

Comment: I can't be in `create.js.erb`. So after sleeping I solved it. It's the new form js renderer. Link here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58129904/5614748

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@arieljuod in the comments section was very instrumental to me solving this. As he mentioned firstly, I am not asking my `format to respond to js` under the `else` condition of the create method. So this is what I did:

**controller create action**

Add the line below to the `else` condition of the create action:

> format.js { render :new }

So my controller action becomes:

```
def create
    @clock_entry = current_user.clock_entries.new(clock_entry_params)
    @clock_entry.set_time_in

    respond_to do |format|
      if @clock_entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @clock_entry, notice: 'Clock entry was successfully created.' }
        format.js { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Clock entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @clock_entry }
      else
        format.js { render :new } # Added this...
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @clock_entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**new.js.erb file**

Then in the `new.js.erb` file, upon rendering the `:new` form, you need to remove or hide what is already there and append a new form that has the error message. So I had to remove the whole form by supplying the `form tag to be hidden` in my `new.js.erb`. So I add this line below to my `new.js.erb` file:

> $('#new-clock-entry form').hide().parent().append("<%= j render 'form', clock_entry: @clock_entry %>")

So new `new.js.erb` file now becomes:

```
$('#new-clock-entry a').hide().parent().append("<%= j render 'form', clock_entry: @clock_entry %>")
$('#new-clock-entry form').hide().parent().append("<%= j render 'form', clock_entry: @clock_entry %>")
```

I think this should be handy to anyone who runs into the same problem.